# How to convert Sybase error message offset to a Stored Procedure line number

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, sybase

I am trying to debug a long stored procedure in Sybase and I get an error message like:

```
 Number (257) Severity (16) State (1) Server (DZUCRINSI225) Procedure (Calculate_FX_Haircut) Implicit conversion from datatype 'CHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query. (4068EE10)
```

I don't know where the error is occurring in the SP. How can I locate it? I guess that the '4068EE10' in the message may be an offset, but I don't know how to make use of it to find the line number. Can anyone help?

I should add that I am using Embarcadero Rapid SQL as an interface to the Sybase server. I'm not certain whether the '4068EE10' is added by Sybase or Embarcadero.

Comment: Showing the code for the SP might help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Rapid Sql for a long while, but Open Client, the Sybase client interface, definitely has messages to the client that contain the line number when the SQL failing is an SP.  Perhaps Rapid SQL is unsing an ODBC connection and the middleware discards Sybase specific things in server message handling?

Can you change your datasource to use a native Sybase connection - I'd expect Rapid Sql to be able to manage?

Why don't you try running this SP in the Sybase sql client isql?

You'll find you get a message that includes the SP name and line number.

Comment: isql does indeed show a line number. I find Rapid SQL much handier to use, so I'd like to make it work there. Thanks for the tip on the native Sybase connection - I'll try that.